# my Div tag show Under openlayer tag

Tags: jquery, dialog, openlayers

i want to show a div tag by JQuery dialog on openlayers project
but the div tag show under Openlayers tag
how can show my div over the Openlayers

Answer (score 0):

in your css setting for that div, set "z-index" higher, see [z-index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-index)